# How to echo variable env in telegraf [[input.exec]]

Tags: bash, sh, telegraf, telegraf-inputs-plugin, telegraf-output-plugins

I have a variable env and I want to get it in telegraf. I use `[[inputs.exec]]`

My code:

```
[[inputs.exec]]
commands = ["echo $val_env"]
data_format = "value"
data_type = "string"
name_override = "value_A"
```

But I can't get this value $val_env. I also test another way such as `[echo "${val_env}"]` or `["$val_env"]`, ... but as same.

How I can get value variable env in commands `[[input.exec]]` telegraf.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `val_env` has to be exported to the environment that is running `telegraf`.

Here's an example, with most of the noise removed for brevity, and I've added to my config exactly what you described:

```bash
$ grep '^\[\[inputs.exec' -A4 /etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf
[[inputs.exec]]
commands = ["echo $val_env"]
data_format = "value"
data_type = "string"
name_override = "value_A"

$ export val_env='Tai Do'

$ telegraf
2022-12-22T11:51:31Z I! Using config file: /etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf
2022-12-22T11:51:31Z I! Starting Telegraf 1.25.0
2022-12-22T11:51:31Z I! Available plugins: 227 inputs, 9 aggregators, 26 processors, 21 parsers, 57 outputs, 2 secret-stores
2022-12-22T11:51:31Z I! Loaded inputs: cpu disk diskio exec kernel mem processes swap system
2022-12-22T11:51:31Z I! Loaded aggregators:
2022-12-22T11:51:31Z I! Loaded processors:
2022-12-22T11:51:31Z I! Loaded secretstores:
2022-12-22T11:51:31Z I! Loaded outputs: exec file
...
value_A,host=***,user=root value="Tai Do" 1671709900000000000
```

Comment: I wrote it in /etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf and the val_env was exported. I "echo value" outside and I can read it. But config inside telegraf. conf and  I run (service telegraf restart). I can't read it

Comment: Since you have to export in the process environment, it all depends on how you start `telegraf`. Your question does not specify that. If it is systemd - [something like this](https://serverfault.com/questions/413397/how-to-set-environment-variable-in-systemd-service). If it is something else - you have to specify how you start it.

Comment: Hi morbeo. I config in telegraf file and run it. I'm researching more and don't resolve this problem